# How to compare 2 string while executing the query

Tags: sql

```
declare @pid int
declare @mid int
declare @tableName varchar(10)
declare @query nvarchar(1000)
declare @subquery nvarchar(300)

set @pid = 1
set @mid = 2
set @query = 'Select * from '+@tableName+' where'

if(@pid is not null)
begin
set @query = @query+' pid ='+@pid+' and'
end

if(@mid is not null)
begin
set @query = @query+' mid ='+@mid+' and'
end
```

if @pid and @mid are not null, get added into the query. If @pid and @mid null, I want to remove 'where' from query. Same for 'and' also, if both get selected.

```
set @subquery = select right('''+@query+''',5)
if(@subquery = 'where')
begin
print @query
-- execute sp_executesql @query
end
```

but unable to compare those, in if clause. Does I need to execute @subquery. If yes, how to take that value?

Comment: I forgot to tell that TableName is also dynamic,that why I choose execute sp_executesql @query.

Comment: @pinky, You also forgot to reply to [mocha's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12245489/how-to-comapre-2-string-while-executing-the-query#comment16414042_12245489)?

Answer (score 2):

> if @pid and @mid are not null,get added into the query.
>
> If @pid and @mid null,I want to remove 'where' from query.
> both get selected.

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
WHERE 1 = 1
  AND (@mid IS NULL OR mid = @mid )
  AND (@pid IS NULL OR pid = @pid)
```

If `@pid` and `@mid` are not `NULL`s, the the previous `WHERE` would be:

```
WHERE 1 = 1
  AND mid = @mid 
  AND pid = @pid
```

Therefore they get added into the query.

If `@pid` and `@mid` are `NULL`s, then the `WHERE` clause would become:

```
WHERE 1 = 1
```

Therefore it would be like it it doesn't exist.

**Note that**, I used `WHERE 1 = 1` in case that the two `@pid` and `@mid` are both `NULL`s, the query is keep working and doesn't break.

Comment: Thanks Mahmoud, for ur help.But my tablename is also dynamic.That's why I choose sp_executesql.I have created dynamically generated query.

Comment: So what's wrong with that? It should work as well with the created dynamically generated query.

Comment: How can I write in from caluse, if my tablename is dynamic?That's why I choosed execute sp_executesql.